# listagg function without group by

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have alot of columns in `select` statement, many of which are derived calculations.

I am trying to group multiple rows into one using `listagg()` in `select` statement, but without having to `group by` rest of columns in `select` statement. Along the lines of `listagg() within group() over (partition by id)`.

Right now I have something along the lines of:

```
select id, listagg(distinct annual_bill_rate, ', ') within group (order by bill_rate) as annual_bill_rate, email, state
from table
group by 1,3,4
```

It doesnt seem to be possible to avoid this group by based on documentation, but are there alternatives? I have 30+ columns, I can't group by all of them. Thank you!

Sample data:

```
id   bill_rate   email        state 
1    0.0035      a@gmail.com  NJ
1    0.0045      a@gmail.com  NJ
1    0.0055      a@gmail.com  NJ
2    0.0065      b@gmail.com  NY
2    0.0075      b@gmail.com  NY
3    0.0085      c@gmail.com  PA
```

Desired result- WITHOUT GROUP BY:

```
id   bill_rate                email        state 
1    0.0035, 0.0045, 0.0055   a@gmail.com  NJ
2    0.0065, 0.0075           b@gmail.com  NY
3    0.0085                   c@gmail.com  PA
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff done

Comment: "but without having to group by rest of columns in select statement". What did you exactly mean about `rest of columns`

Comment: @Muhammadvakili `id, email, state` (in reality its 30+ columns)

Comment: No. You need to include those 30+ columns in your group by in order to group by them. You could maybe do a `SELECT DISTINCT <all those columns except bill_rate> FROM TABLE` and then seperately `SELECT listagg(bill_rate), id FROM table GROUP BY id` then join them together on ID. I think that's dumb and definitely slower, but it's your system. It's really not a big deal to just put the columns in your group by though, is it? It's just a copy/paste job.

Comment: Are all fields except `bill_rate` equal for a specific id?

Comment: @JNevill No, this expense lot to use all fields in the group by. It must have a simple solution.

Comment: I'd like to see the explain on both methods: a straight `group by` that OP is trying to avoid vs a `group by` joined to a `SELECT DISTINCT`. I'm betting the latter is more expensive.

Comment: @Muhammadvakili anything that isn't equal will be put into a listagg() so yes

Comment: @JNevill many columns in select are derived calculations (case when end etc.) and renames (x as y), so copy paste will not do. `over()` would be beautiful here

Comment: But why? Why are you trying to avoid typing the GROUP BY. Are you trying to make the query perform better and so you are trying to avoid the GROUP BY or is this just to get out of typing the group by out? You aren't going to find a reasonable solution that doesn't ALSO cause your query to perform worse, and that's a hell of a trade off to save some keystrokes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a not so great idea to avoid typing the GROUP BY. It will almost definitely be slower and it's much more difficult to read and understand. I would be an unhappy fella if I ran into this in production code:

```
WITH table_distinct AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT id, email, state
    FROM table
)
,table_group_by AS
(
    SELECT id, listagg(distinct annual_bill_rate, ', ') within group (order by bill_rate) as annual_bill_rate
    FROM table
    GROUP BY id
)
SELECT 
    td.*,
    tgb.annual_bill_rate        
FROM table_distinct td
    INNER JOIN table_group_by tgb
        ON td.id = tgb.id;
```

Now you really only need monkey with that `table_distinct` CTE to add more columns to your result set.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution to your problem without a Distinct or Group By clause usage.
You can use LISTAGG as an analytical function as well and then you can remove the duplicates using row_number. PSB -

```
select * from
(select 
id, listagg(annual_bill_rate, ', ') within group (order by bill_rate) over (partition by id order by id) as annual_bill_rate,
email, state, row_number() over (partition by id order by id) RN
from table) Tab where RN=1;
```